# Optimize a where request on Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Apache Spark (and Scala) and I want  to apply a simple sql request just after reading a csv file and load it on a DF without the need of creating an additional dataframe nor a temporary view or table.

This is the initial request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT city from cities
WHERE id IN ("10", "20")
AND year IN ("2017", "2018")
```

This is what I tried on Scala :

```
val cities = spark.read.options(Map("header" -> "true", "delimiter" -> ";")).csv("test.csv").select("city").distinct.where(""" id IN ("10", "20") AND year IN ("2017", "2018")"""))

cities.show(20)
```

But it doesn't work. Concretely, it seems that the problem occurs because it didn't recognize the two other columns in the dataframe (since I selected only one column before). So, I had to select initially those three columns and then save a temporary table (a view) and then select the wanted column in a new dataframe. I find this approach too long and too heavy.

Can you help me to fix this please ???
Thank you !

Comment: Change the where to filter and move it before select

Comment: yeah it works !!! thank you very much

Comment: No problem, amigo

Comment: @sramalingam24 afaik `where` and `filter` is the same, or am  I wrong?

Comment: Yup, one and the same. Just eye candy for SQL folks

Comment: @sramalingam24 then why do you recommend to change where to filter?

Comment: Filter is clearer in df context

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost correct, you just need to move the `where` statement before the `select(..).distinct` :

```
val cities = spark.read
  .options(Map("header" -> "true", "delimiter" -> ";"))
  .csv("test.csv")
  .where($"id".isin("10", "20") and $"year".isin("2017", "2018"))
  .select("city").distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark scala API is more imperative than declarative (unlike SQL) which is why after you `select("city")` you lost all the other fields in the dataframe. and why, as others noted, you should filter/where before you do the select. This is a bit confusing as the Scala DSL is similar in syntax to the SQL

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by sramalingam24 and Raphael Roth, the `where` has to be applied before selecting the required field from the DataFrame. Filter and where both gives the same result as shown below. The dropDuplicates() will remove the Duplicates in the city column.

```
    val cities = spark.read.options(Map("header" -> "true", "delimiter" -> ";"))
       .csv("test.csv")
       .filter($"id".isin("10", "20") and $"year".isin("2017", "2018"))
       .select("city")
       .dropDuplicates()
```